# Get requests from python aren't sent on php

Tags: php, python

I send my data through get request from python to php website (it's on hosting) and it doesn't work. But when it's on localhost it works

Php:

```
<?php
$req_dump = print_r($_REQUEST, true);
$fp = file_put_contents('text.txt', $req_dump, FILE_APPEND);
 ?>
```

Python:

```
import requests

while True:
    theWeight = input("Enter ")
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:81/index.php', params={'weight': theWeight})
    print(r.url)
```

I edit only this string for the site that's on hosting and it doesn't get the GET requests

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com/index.php', params={'weight': theWeight})
```

Comment: Maybe your hosting is in HTTPS?

Comment: no, it is http://

Comment: Ok, if you do a GET request with your browser it works? (http://example.com/index.php?weight=8)

Comment: yes, it works then

Comment: I have done this one day ago and it worked, but I lost files that I did.

Comment: I tried to do the python code on online compiler and it worked, I don't know why

Comment: What is the result of r.text on when you exec the code from your PC?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/k5hAEZ0.png

Comment: Oh ok, I think I have figured out. I will post all in an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your page requires JavaScript for work correctly as shown in the r.text output (i.imgur.com/k5hAEZ0.png).

Now your PHP code doesn't anything other than write the .txt file, there is some HTML/JS code under that?

If not it can be that your hosting provider web server has some filter for "no-js-enabled" HTTP requests? I find it strange that the code stops working only on the hosting server

Another way of solving this problem is by using another python lib that supports JavaScript: [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Well it was because of the hosting, I only changed it and it works